# GA : Session % in which the user do not visit the front page

Tags: google-analytics

Using google analytics , is it possible to figure out in how many sessions the user did not visit the front page ?

EDIT:

the ga:sessions metric cannot be queried with ga:pagePath or ga:landingpagePath
[GA : how can there be more sessions number when using the filter landingpagePath as compared when using the filter pagePath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010907/ga-how-can-there-be-more-sessions-number-when-using-the-filter-landingpagepath)

can i safely use with [query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) the metric `ga:sessions` with segment`sessions::condition::ga:landingpagePath==/` and `sessions::condition::ga:landingpagePath==/` and substract the 2values ?

Answer (score 1):

It is. You have 2 ways, with filters or segments. Either way, you need to exclude users where [`ga:pagePath`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath) match `/` (or whatever your homepage URL is).

Practically, you can use the [API query explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to test your API request, which filter will look like this:

[image]

Comment: if i use this filter on metric ga:sessions, does that really give me the number of sessions in which the user never visit the front page OR the number of sessions in which the user did not enter the site with the front page ?

Comment: cannot find the description of pagePath in the doc

Comment: The description of `ga:pagePath` is on the link I provided (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_pagepath), for entrances, use `ga:landingPagePath` (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=page_tracking&jump=ga_landingpagepath)

Comment: 25% of sessions never visiting the website home page, very useful info to consider

Comment: how to explain in certain site when the ga:pagePath==/ is inferior of ga:landingPagePath==/  ??